# iPhone app submission process

Tags: iphone, applications, apple-inc

I've submitted my first app on the 20th November but the status is still "Waiting for review", has anyone had longer than this or similar waiting times?

Comment: Bear in mind, you submitted it on the lead-up to Thanksgiving. :) Given the likely tens or hundreds of "shopping" apps coming out, you're in line, at a longer than usual time.

Comment: Oh great and i'm not even from the USA! (UK) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approval process varies and there’s no exact number. The factor that determines this is the number of apps in the approval queue. I don’t remember where I read that 95% of the apps where approved within 14 days. I believe this came in a “message” in the dev accounts. But it was more than a year ago.

You can see more information in your Developer Account by going to the [approval](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/) page. (You need a paid account to access that).

I haven’t submitted an iPhone App but in my near experience, it’s around two weeks.

Comment: thanks for this. I have a paid account, you need one to submit apps! I'm aware that its an opaque process Apple put you through, was just wondering what others experiences were :)

Comment: 14 days still sounds about right; my vendors are averaging that these days, and it's rare for us to go over that.

Answer (score 0):

I waited for 8 days with [my first iPhone app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/colorblind-vision/id401516863?mt=8). It was incredibly fast IMO. I guess the approval times depends on the type of app you are making and how well your app is put together.